# why react-select default value doesn't show

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I using react select like following code1. But In react-select doesnt show default value.
**Two console.log are show me same value correctly all time** .
(defaultArray is just a variable)

And when I use code2. Default value does not show too. When I use code3 . Default value showed.
That is too curious to me.
Please give me advice.

### **edit1** ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

I found new one. useEffect may be caused it's part of problem. 
when I remove [useEffect] and set Array. work well.
But Fundamental problem is invisible yet.

```
  const [defaultArray, setDefaultArray] = useState([
    { value: "30", label: "A" },
    { value: "31", label: "B" },
    { value: "32", label: "C" },
    { value: "33", label: "D" },
    { value: "34", label: "E" },
  ]);
```

### ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

code1

```
import React from "react";

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const SelectPersonality: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = props => {

 const [defaultArray, setDefaultArray] = useState(Array());

 useEffect (() => {
    setDefaultArray([
      { value: "30", label: "A" },
      { value: "31", label: "B" },
      { value: "32", label: "C" },
      { value: "33", label: "D" },
      { value: "34", label: "E" },
    ]);
  }, []);

  return (
      <div>
        {console.log(defaultArray)}
        {console.log([
          { value: "30", label: "A" },
          { value: "31", label: "B" },
          { value: "32", label: "C" },
          { value: "33", label: "D" },
          { value: "34", label: "E" },
        ])}
        <Select
          isMulti
          defaultValue={defaultArray}
          options={character_options}
          onChange={value => Change(value)}
          className="select_personality_character"
        />
      </div>
  );
};

export default SelectPersonality;
```

code2

```
        {console.log(defaultArray)}
        {console.log([
          { value: "30", label: "A" },
          { value: "31", label: "B" },
          { value: "32", label: "C" },
          { value: "33", label: "D" },
          { value: "34", label: "E" },
        ])}
        <Select
          isMulti
          defaultValue={
            defaultArray
              ? defaultArray
              : [
                  { value: "30", label: "A" },
                  { value: "31", label: "B" },
                  { value: "32", label: "C" },
                  { value: "33", label: "D" },
                  { value: "34", label: "E" },
                ]
          }
          options={character_options}
          onChange={value => Change(value)}
          className="select_personality_character"
        />
```

code3

```
      <Select
          isMulti
          defaultValue={
            defaultArray
              ? [
                  { value: "30", label: "A" },
                  { value: "31", label: "B" },
                  { value: "32", label: "C" },
                  { value: "33", label: "D" },
                  { value: "34", label: "E" },
                ]
              : defaultArray
          }
          options={character_options}
          onChange={value => Change(value)}
          className="select_personality_character"
        />
```

Comment: Hi, will it be possible to show a bit more of the code and its implementation, it is difficult to visualize the issue without a broader context. At first glance it looks like and assignment issue.

Comment: Ok I edited above code.

Comment: You can try to check if defaultArray is set or !== than null or empty array before rendering the select component

Comment: You dont need useEffect is you can initialize the state on its creation

Comment: Real code use axios. so I have to set data as array state.

Comment: I see, but the axios call is done from another component correct? and you are passing the data as a prop to SelectPersonality?

Comment: axios is executed in useEffect and I already checked data in console. And this  is unrelated to essence of this problem. Essence is why select component    doesnt show statedata seted in useEffect.Please see code1.

Comment: Is this what you are after? https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-shamir-5o2fhreact-select-example-5o2fh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I just thinking

Answer (score 0):

it seems that defaultArray is not equal to the array ( read the code bellow, is much easier to understand than to explain )

```
defaultArray !=  [
                  { value: "30", label: "A" },
                  { value: "31", label: "B" },
                  { value: "32", label: "C" },
                  { value: "33", label: "D" },
                  { value: "34", label: "E" },
                ]
```

defaultArray it may be an anidated array

```
[
 [
    { value: "30", label: "A" },
    { value: "31", label: "B" },
    { value: "32", label: "C" },
    { value: "33", label: "D" },
    { value: "34", label: "E" },
  ]
]
```

please check and let me know

### edit:

the code2 and code3 gives us the hint that defaultArray:

- is not null
- is not undefined
- it may be empty

like you said into the edit, it may be useEffect fault

basically you initialize the array, render the component, populate the array with the values

try this :

```
 const [defaultArray, setDefaultArray] = useState([
    { value: "30", label: "A" },
    { value: "31", label: "B" },
    { value: "32", label: "C" },
    { value: "33", label: "D" },
    { value: "34", label: "E" },
  ]);
```

you should populate the array before rendering

---

also, keep this in mind

```
const dependenciesArray = []
useEffect(()=>{}, dependenciesArray) // this will block the rerender of the component at state update
useEffect(()=>{}) // not passing an array will force a rerender of the component at each state update
```

so if you want dinamic select values, don't pass the second argument into the `useEffect()`

see docs: [useEffect docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)

Comment: I use  `defaultValue={defaultArray[0]}` but nothing change.

Comment: Try defaultValue={defaultArray}

Comment: I used nested array but nothing change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Select from "react-select";

export default function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>React-select example</h1>
            <SelectComponent />
        </div>
    );
}

const SelectComponent = () => {
    const options = [
        { value: "30", label: "A" },
        { value: "31", label: "B" },
        { value: "32", label: "C" },
        { value: "33", label: "D" },
        { value: "34", label: "E" },
        { value: "35", label: "F" },
        { value: "36", label: "G" },
        { value: "37", label: "H" },
        { value: "38", label: "I" }
    ];

    const defaults = [options[0], options[1], options[2],  options[3]];

    return (
        <div>
            <Select
                isMulti
                defaultValue={defaults}
                options={options}
            />
        </div>
    );
};
```

I think the problem is that your default values dont match the options values, you are feeding the select component 2 different data arrays and it gets confused

Comment: what is change from your first answer except looks ? I tried your first answer but nothing change.  In your first code .I added `console.log('aaaa')` after ELSE  but nothing  was output.

Comment: Console.log was output same value. So my case was no problem in point of another array value.

Comment: Are the 2 arrays the same and have the same key value pairs?, because you are correct you can use 2 different data entries but I just test it and they must have the exact same values.

Comment: I used another array in defaultValue and options now. And 
 it's worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I resolved this problem but I still don't understand what caused it.

I had to add `{defaultArray !== undefined && (~)}` . This code doesn't work without it.

I can't understand.

why....

```
import React from "react";

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const SelectPersonality: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = props => {

const [defaultArray, setDefaultArray] = useState<Array<{ [key: string]: string }>>();

 useEffect (() => {
    setDefaultArray([
      { value: "30", label: "A" },
      { value: "31", label: "B" },
      { value: "32", label: "C" },
      { value: "33", label: "D" },
      { value: "34", label: "E" },
    ]);
  }, []);

  return (
       <div> 
　　　　 {defaultArray !== undefined && (
          <Select
            isMulti
            defaultValue={defaultArray}
            options={character_options}
            onChange={value => change(value)}
            className="select_personality_character"
          />
        )}
      </div>
  );
};

export default SelectPersonality;
```